# Can I combine input components like this using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm now trying to build a form like this. (Combine two input components)

[image]

I found there are `list-group` components and `input-group` components:
[list group](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/list-group/#basic-example)

But I wonder can I combine the input components like a list group?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap classes on any element, their name is usually just a suggestion. Just because the class is called `list-group`, doesn't mean it can't be applied to inputs for the same effect.

These classes only define the visual appearance and not the functionality or semantics of an element, so feel free to mix them any way you find visually pleasing.

For example,

```
<form name="somename" action="someaction" class="list-group">
  <input class="list-group-item" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email">
  <input class="list-group-item" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
```

is valid and displays as expected. For more control over how the inputs are styled and for adding more elements to a single row, you can nest your inputs in divs, like so:

```
<form class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <input  type="text" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply give the Form Inputs the list-group-item class:

```
  <div class="list-group">
    <input  class="list-group-item" type="text" />
    <input  class="list-group-item" type="text" />
  </div>
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7g2s8b1/).